# Request to merge/burn [request] and cousins

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request, synonym-request

The [request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/request) tag is definitely a catch all and completely unrelated to [node-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-request) and [npm-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm-request).

How do we handle these ones?

Oh also there's [http-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-request) too!

Personally I'd like to think "request", the npm module, is popular enough that it should get ownership of [npm-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm-request) and [node-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-request). All unrelated tagged questions should be retagged with [http-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-request).

(Similar with how [python-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-requests) is a synonym of [requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/requests).)

Comment: Can anyone tell me why request is used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614099/mysql-not-superior-operator)? Because, afaik I can tell (with my limited postgresql background), it's used because "I have a request"

Comment: Honestly it has no business there. I'm thinking it should be like [tag:api]

Comment:  I suspected. On my phone so couldn't check. Thanks @nightshadequeen

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think it's entirely possible for someone to be an expert in [HTTP requests](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html), or at least it's no less possible for someone to be an expert in [request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/request) as compared to being an expert in [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json). And looking in the sidebar, it does seem to be reasonably used most of the time, with related tags [http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js), [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) ([mostly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611861/why-setconnectionrequesttimeout-doesnt-stop-my-1-min-get-request) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735861/check-if-post-is-succesfull-android) [making](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039630/customize-a-sql-query-to-check-column-from-get-request) [requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092584/filter-causing-post-request-body-to-become-empty)), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) (there's also the [python-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-requests) for that specific module, but there's [several](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) [python](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) modules for making requests, and [several](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyramid/) [web](https://www.djangoproject.com/) [frameworks](http://flask.pocoo.org/) that can receive requests), [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax), [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) ([also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589996/c-sharp-https-request) [usually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534123/checking-request-using-selenium) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216571/how-to-get-request-header-values-on-cuniversal) [making](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680351/how-can-i-send-get-request-with-sockets) [requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663751/c-sharp-request-api-livechat)), and [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). Might be a bit of a metatag, but it does seem to mostly accurate.

Of course, there's the [odd question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614099/mysql-not-superior-operator) or [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31612286/how-can-i-get-elements-in-a-folder-with-javacript) that seem to be tagged [request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/request) simply because they're requests. There doesn't seem to be too many of these, though. (In the first four pages, those are the only odd ones, as far as I can tell)

Personally, I don't think [request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/request) should be synonymized to [node-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-request) or [npm-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm-request). Look through the tag now, it's there's a mix of programming languages being used, and of the 5580 questions tagged [request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/request), only 574 are tagged [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js).

If any change is to be made (and I'm not convinced that changes need to be made) I think it should mostly just vanish, so no one has a place to tag their "I have a request: can someone teach me Javascript?" questions to. Every other question should be retagged to [http-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-request) (or perhaps the relevant library, if a library is relevant.) But, again, not convinced.

(I also don't think [python-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-requests) should be a synonym of [requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/requests), because python does not rule the world of requests<sup>1</sup>, but that's a discussion for a different day.)

---

<sup><sub>**1**: Strong desire to snark about "give-me-code" questions existing for every language, not just python.</sub></sup>

Comment: Totally agree but I bet there's an [tag:http-request] too... So what do we do about all of them? Does "request" become the core of "node-request" because it is the official name of the project?